# Converting daily data to weekly data in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the DAILY returns of industry portfolios in SAS.

I would like to calculate the WEEKLY returns.

The daily returns are in percentage so I think that should just be the sum of returns during each week.

Obvious problems I am facing is that the weeks can have a different number of days in.

The table I have in SAS is in the following format:

```
INDUSTRY_NUMBER DATE DAILY_RETURN
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried this:

```
proc expand data=Day_result
out=Week_result from=day to=week;
Industry_Number Trading_Date;
convert Value_weighted_return / method=aggregate observed=total;
run;
```

The daily data is in `Day_Result` when I remove the forth line i.e.

```
proc expand data=Day_result
out=Week_result from=day to=week;
convert Value_weighted_return / method=aggregate observed=total;
run;
```

This works as in it does what I want it to do but it doesn't do it for each category it does it for the whole table.

So if I have 40 categories I want the weekly returns for each category.

The second set of code provides the weekly return for every category.

EXAMPLE DATA:

```
data have;
    format trading_date date9.;
    infile datalines dlm=',';
    input trading_date:ddmmyy10. industry_number value_weighted_return;
    datalines;
19/01/2000,1, -0.008
20/01/2000,1, 0.008
23/01/2000,1, 0.008
24/01/2000,1, -0.007
25/01/2000,1, -0.009
26/01/2000,1, 0.008
27/01/2000,1, -0.008
30/01/2000,1, 0.003
31/01/2000,1, -0.001
01/02/2000,1, 0.004
02/02/2000,2, -0.008
03/02/2000,2, -0.005
06/02/2000,2, -0.004
07/02/2000,2, -0.009
08/02/2000,2, 0.002
09/02/2000,2, 0.006
10/02/2000,2, 0.008
13/02/2000,2, 0.008
14/02/2000,2, 0.002
15/02/2000,2, 0.01
16/02/2000,2, -0.008
;
run;
```

Comment: please give sample input and sample output, so that someone can help you

Comment: Describe what you have tried, and show examples of data and results.  Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I have provided an example, does this make more sense @Richard

Comment: @Stu Sztukowski can you see the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your data by `INDUSTRY_NUMBER Trading_Date`, use `INDUSTRY_NUMBER` as a by-group, identify your time variable.

```
proc sort data=have;
    by industry_number trading_date;
run;
```

Next, convert your data into a time-series to remove any time gaps. Set any missing days as the previous value since it does not change on those trading days (e.g. weekends, bank holidays, etc.).

```
proc timeseries data=have
                out=have_ts;
    by industry_number;
    id trading_date interval=day 
                    setmissing=previous
                    accumulate=average
    ;

    var value_weighted_return;
run;
```

Finally, take the time-series output and convert it from day to week. Since you are using weights, you may want to use `average` rather than `total`.

```
proc expand data=have_ts
            out=have_ts_week
            from=day
            to=week
    ;
    by industry_number;
    id trading_date;

    convert Value_weighted_return / method=aggregate observed=average;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try to run this it creates a table with 0 observations

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data that can either be downloaded or is in `datalines` form?

Comment: Thanks @Stu I added some example data

Comment: @user11140153 Unfortunately I am not seeing it in the original question. Can you try adding it again?

Comment: Sorry for that I added it to your answer by mistake

Comment: Thanks for showing the example data. I have made edits based on its structure. The above solution should now work for you.